# Save user progress in DB with multiple Dates.

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to make a table in my DB to store user score (Like SO does). I found this post [How do I record daily rankings for a model in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428120/how-do-i-record-daily-rankings-for-a-model-in-django) and even though its exactly what I need, I cant get the accepted solution to work.

I have problems to create a proper model.

```
class Rank(models.Model):
  class Meta(object):
    unique_together = (("date", "user"))
  date = models.DateField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now())
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  value = models.IntegerField(default=1)

  def value1(self):
    try:
        x = self.user.userprofile.get_point() #reference a function in another model
    except:
        x = 1
    return x
```

But this gives me a structure like this: [image]

While I need something like

```
User/date: Date1|  Date2  | Date3 .....

user1:       15  |   16    |  17.....

user2:        2  |   6     |  12.....
```

Where the numbers represent the points and `Date1` represents 01.01.2017 and so on. Im using PostgreSQL.

Please don't answer with "just use a ManyToManyField"
or similar. I want to understand the subject and some details are appreciated.

Comment: You could keep this table structure and after that, make queries to display the data the way you want, in a view.

Comment: well you can create a new table called dates and add a foreignkey that refer to the rank model